# Save OpenCV Frame as object

Tags: java, c++, opencv, serialization

I am currently working on saving OpenCV Frame as object. I will be saving a lot of frames onto disk, so I am looking for the fastest way to do this.

Could anyone please give some hints to me? It could be either in Java or C++..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of consecutive frames with a lot of similarities, you could save it as a video file with MJPEG compression. Obviously, I'm assuming you don't mind the lossy compression.

Comment: I want to make it more lossless.

Comment: I am also thinking about if I could open an 100GB virtual memory to just keep all of frames on heap...

Comment: If I want to save them in a single json file with increasing numeric order, such as.. I see there is a problem of read write lock..

Comment: Probably I want to save in separate Json file.

Comment: There are some lossless video compression codecs out there that you can use too.

Comment: You are right. I want to dirty read those video frames. Or if I make those video into 15 seconds chunk to simulate dirty read, I will lose some frames when I open a new video clips....